# PHP code to Javascript

Tags: php, javascript

How can I convert this PHP code to javascript? I wanna use .js file to insert other pages. If there are other ways please tell me.
thanks! :)

```
<?
include 'config.php';
$select = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `currency`");
$num=mysql_num_rows($select);

    while($row=mysql_fetch_object($select))
    {

        $id=$row->id;
        $qveyana=$row->qveyana;
        $simbolo=$row->simbolo;
        $kursi=$row->kursi;
        $zrda=$row->zrda;
        $drosha=$row->drosha;           

?>
<table border="0" width="300" cellpadding="" cellspacing="0">
<tr bgcolor="#CCCCCC" bordercolor="#FF0000"><td width="22"><i.mg src="<? echo  $drosha; ?>" width="20"  /></td><td width="50"><? echo $qveyana; ?></td><td width="40"><? echo $simbolo; ?></td><td><? echo $kursi; ?></td><td><? echo $zrda; ?></td></tr>

</table>
<? } ?>
```

Comment: I think you should review the difference between PHP and Javascript, why would you convert code from PHP to Javascript?

Comment: Your code is messy, could you please fix it

Comment: You should keep using PHP scripts for server side actions and if you need to call "php" scripts from javascript, check for ajax (jquery etc) since they can help you achieve what you need.

Comment: For some reason I can't retag this, but it has nothing to do with Java.

Comment: PHP is not code translation system. Provide how you tried porting app and exactly how it failed.

Comment: As a side note: 1. It's a good practice to name variables in English. So everybody is able to understand it. `mysql_*` API is deprecated. Use either `PDO` or `mysqli_*`.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't ever have a direct javascript <-> database connection.

What you would use is a intermediate step,

For reading, a php script that gets data from DB then generates a 'json' stream for the javascript to read.

Or posting the results of a form to a php script that actually inserts it into the database.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there are any javascript DB connectors.

Even if there are db connectors you wouldn't want to connect directly from the user with his javascript to your database. This would be a great security hole.

Comment: That is not at all a good idea to rely on javascript DB connector unless you really know what you want. Here I don't think it is the case.

Comment: Without a javascript db connector its not possible. And even with a javascript db connector I wouldn't do it. :)

Comment: I wouldn't even have talked about it, it could be misleading for him :(

Comment: Hmm. I thought "great security hole" wouldn't mislead him.

Comment: ok, can i print this php result in other page with one link EX:

<script language="javascript" src="http://currency.boom.ge/moduls/currency_bar.php?id=3&w=173&h=91">
</script>

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are not using server-side Javascript (node.js) then what I think you want to do is to stick with your PHP code on the server but call that from JS (in the browser), rather than trying to recreate it. You can't access your server-side database directly from JS running in a browser.

If you have, for example, a webpage called getcurrency.php that contains the code you pasted above then you can use AJAX to call this URL from JS whenever you like. The jQuery JS framework would make this easy for you: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/