# get access to database from javascript

Tags: javascript

I am getting records from database in my HTML

```
      <g:each in="${index}">

     ${""+it.indexDate+""+it.value }
     </g:each>
```

It's working fine, but I want to use this record below in my javascript:

I want to do some thing like this

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
if(it.value>10){
 alert("yes")
}
```

Is there a way I can do that?

Comment: Please make your question clearer

Comment: i simply want to access my database in Javascript .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you want to do exactly the same as what is described in [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8204844/php-code-to-javascript/8204864#comment10084801_8204864).
Trying to access your database directly Javascript might be feasible but it is never a good idea.

In fact, the Javascript runs on the client side, and you don't want your clients to be able to mess  up with your data. I would highly recommend using [**Ajax**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29). That is to say, be able to **asynchronously** call the server side (PHP or any other server-side language you use) from the client side to request what you need from the database.

Comment: yeah , but i have already accessed my database records in my html , below html i have javascript , so is that a possibility that i can use whatever i got in the html in my Javascript, or can i write html code inside JavaScript .. you can review my question again to understand my point . Thanks

Comment: Then you just retrieve them in the dom with JQuery or any other comfortable mean. Just get the element with a JQuery selector: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/